# relationship to non-key column in EF6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

im trying to have a foreign key on non-primary column and this is my models .
its one-to-many relationship . questions can have multiple answers . but answers only have on questions.

for model which hold the user questions :

```
public class QQuestions
{

    public QQuestions()
    {
        Answers = new List<QAnswers>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QId { get; set; }

    public string QuestionContext { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QAnswers> Answers { get; set; }

}
```

and the model which hold the users answers :

```
public class QAnswers
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QId")]
    public QQuestions QQuestions { get; set; }

    public string AnswerContext { get; set; }

}
```

but when i try to insert data in sql i got this error :

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.QAnswers_dbo.QQuestions_QId". The conflict occurred in database "ResaleJadvali", table "dbo.QQuestions", column 'Id'.
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix that .
thanks .

Comment: What is the primary key of QQuestion? QId or Id? In the QAnswer you have to remove "public int QId" and set the attribute [ForeignKey("Id")] (I suppose this is the primary key of QQuestion object).

Comment: thanks . the primary key of QQuestion is Id but i want to have a relationship with QId . all i want to do is : in my webapi when i call GetQuestion and get it an id it return me the QQuestion plus all Answers for that question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not yet recognize non-pk candidate keys as a target for a foreign key (EF work item is here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299) - you must reference the primary key of the related entity in your foreign key.